# 405 Method Not Allowed for POST

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a very simple spring boot application, which is secured by the following code:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
          .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
          .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
```

the idea is to secure "admin" portion. It exposes a REST API. 
The problem is all the POSTS returns

> 405 Method Not Allowed

If I remove the security starter from the application, it works. This makes me believe that the security configuration is the problem. But I cannot find out how.

Comment: How is your login handler?

Comment: auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
  .usersByUsernameQuery(
   "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
  .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
   "select username, role from user_roles where username=?"); But it shouldn't matter, as this method is outside the admin portion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be easy.

POSTs and PUT requests would not be allowed if CSRF is enabled,and spring boot enables those by default.

Just add this to your configuration code :

```
.csrf().disable()
```

that is :

```
http.
.csrf().disable().
authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
          .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
          .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
```

Refer docs ,if you need to enable CSRF :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if using Spring Security SAML extension and your `SAMLUserDetailsService` returns a `UsernameNotFoundException`. Seems pretty counter-intuitive, but that's what it does by default (in my experience).